# Can committing to GitHub every day hurt your career possibilities?

Tags: work-life-balance

I have a consistent GitHub streak for a few months now. 
I plan to continue doing this indefinitely.
I work on my Open Source projects on my time at home.

I have heard of employers being frustrated that an employee makes time for Open Source work every day and is not working overtime (unpaid) for them. It's like a betrayal, especially if the employee is not excelling in their work (in the employers eyes at least)...

Is there any way lots of GitHub activity to look bad for potential employers?

Comment: It's a terrible idea if you want to work for assholes, yes.

Comment: in my view, you doing this sort of stuff at home instead of anything else is like "Woah this guy is a dedicated coder. He must be good" So why would anyone wanna fire that?

Comment: I'm aware of all of the good things that can come from this. I'm just afraid that in some circumstances it can be considered a bad thing.

Comment: VTC - Completely opinion based.

Comment: It's absurd what you have heard. Avoid hearing from unreasonable people.

Answer (score 5):

What you do in your own time is your own business.

Obviously if occasional work commitments means that you need to work on project work to make up some time, you'll do that instead of GitHubbing, right?

Comment: Yes, but you are asking that question. How many people just won't and will presume that if the person is active after hours, he/she can't be counted on to work overtime.

Comment: Most reasonable people would assume that people would drop their personal ad-hoc projects for their day job if needed.

Comment: @Snow realy would you drop going to see your kids play at school canceling a pre planed meal with friends

Answer (score 4):

> I have heard of employers being frustrated that an employee makes time for Open Source work every day and is not working overtime (unpaid) for them.

I've never encountered this before, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are people out there like that. If working on Open Source in your free time is important to you though, do you really want to work for an employer that thinks like that?

So could this harm your job chances at a few places? It's certainly possible. Should you care about those few places? No, I don't think so. Any employer who will value you is someone who will see your enthusiasm for coding (and hours of experience and learning they don't have to pay for) as a huge positive, not a negative.

This is all assuming of course (like [Snow said](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/111263/16983)) that you never let your Open Source work interfere with your ability to get your primary job done.